# How to check if BeautifulSoup tag is a certain tag?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, wordprocessingml

If I find a certain tag using `beautifulsoup`:

```
styling = paragraphs.find_all('w:rpr')
```

I look at the next tag. I only want to use that tag if it is a `<w:t>` tag. How do I check what type of tag the next tag is?

I tried `element.find_next_sibling().startswith('<w:t')` for the element but it says `NoneType object is not callable`. I also tried `element.find_next_sibling().find_all('<w:t'>)` but it doesn't return anything.

```
for element in styling:
    next = element.find_next_sibling()
    if(#next is a <w:t> tag):
        ...
```

i am using `beautifulsoup` and would like to stick with it and not add `eTree` or other parser if possible with bs4.

Comment: if you search tag then don't use `< >` in its name. Tag with `:` means it has `namespace` - `<namespace:tag_name>` - and it may need to use namespace options to search it.

Comment: `item.name` gives item's tag name

Comment: maybe create code with some data which makes problem because I have to problem to get tag `w:t` with `element.find_all('w:t')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `item.name` you can see tag's name.

Problem is that between tags there are elements `NavigableString` which are also treated as sibling elements and they gives `None`.

You would have to skip these elements or you could get all siblings and use `for` loop to find first `<w:t>` and exit loop with `break`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<div>
  <w:rpr></w:rpr>
  <w:t>A</w:t>
</div>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_wrpr = soup.find_all('w:rpr')
for wrpr in all_wrpr:

    next_tag = wrpr.next_sibling
    print('name:', next_tag.name) # None

    next_tag = wrpr.next_sibling.next_sibling
    #next_tag = next_tag.next_sibling
    print('name:', next_tag.name) # w:t
    print('text:', next_tag.text) # A

#name: None
#name: w:t
#text: A

print('---')

all_siblings = wrpr.next_siblings
for item in all_siblings:
    if item.name == 'w:t':
       print('name:', item.name) # w:t
       print('text:', item.text) # A
       break # exit after first <w:t>

#name: w:t
#text: A
```

---

**EDIT:** If you test code with HTML formated little different

```
text = '''<div>
  <w:rpr></w:rpr><w:t>A</w:t>
</div>'''
```

then there will be no `NavigableString` between tags and first method will fail but second method will still work.